# AngularJs - Using ng-controller with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-controller

This works:

```
<div ng-include="'login.html'" flex ng-if="!loggedIn" ng-controller="LoginController"></div>
```

However, this doesn't (`{{test}}` outputs nothing):

```
<ng-include src="'login.html'" flex ng-if="!loggedIn" ng-controller="LoginController"></ng-include>
```

Is there any reason? Or is it a bug?

login.html:

```
<p>{{test}}</p>
```

LoginController:

```
function LoginController($scope){
    $scope.test = 'login';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?  It doesn't show up?  The controller doesn't pass in scope variable?  It displays a monkey?

Comment: See my updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where "loggedIn" is defined, but when I define it on a parent controller, both syntaxes work as expected.

[Plunkr](https://plunker.co/edit/dYq0LHijIy)

```
<div ng-controller="PrntCtrl">
      <div ng-include="'test.html'" flex ng-if="!loggedIn" ng-controller="TestCtrl"></div>
      <ng-include src="'test.html'" flex ng-if="!loggedIn" ng-controller="TestCtrl"></ng-include>
    </div>
```

Some questions to consider:
What version of angular are you using?
How is your app defined and how is the controller registered with the app?
Where is "loggedIn" defined?

Answer (score 0):

Because this directive accepts only 3 arguments:

- ngInclude | src  = string
- onload (optional) = string
- autoscroll (optional) = string

...according to the [ngInclude Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

EDIT:

you can solve simply wrap it in another element...

```
<div ng-if="!loggedIn" ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div ng-include="'login.html'" flex></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then why can I put `ng-if` there? `ng-if` works on both examples.

Comment: you can solve simply wrap it in another element... `<div ng-if="!loggedIn" ng-controller="LoginController"><div ng-include="'login.html'" flex></div></div>`